# WPF Scrolling datagrid in expander

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I have a datagrid in expander and gatagrid has more than 10 columns. Then datagrid in expander
should be scrolled. But it can not be scrolled for see the other columns.  My code is below.

```
                <Expander Header="Attribute" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="1" >
                           <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" Height="257" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  MinHeight="200" Name="gridview1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGrid>
                     </ScrollViewer>
                </Expander>
```

Comment: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Change this to visible?

Comment: It didn't work.. I just saw the scrollbar bad it is hidden to scroll @mcalex

Comment: @Isi did my solution work for you ?

Comment: @Sisyphe i have solved with diffrent solution. Nevertheless, thank you very much..

Comment: @Isi : Glad to read you solved your issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

DataGrid have a ScrollViewer embedded in its ControlTemplate.

So you can do two things :

If you really want to use your own ScrollViewer (but please be aware that by doing so, you will loose features like DataGrid virtualization ) this code should work :

```
<Expander Header="Attribute" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" >
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid Height="257"  MinHeight="200" Name="gridview1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Expander>
```

However, I would advise you simply do this :

```
<Expander Header="Attribute" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid Height="257"  MinHeight="200" Name="gridview1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
    </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

The DataGrid.Style should not even be necessary.